# How to create a bearer token with js (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, bearer-token

After searching the web, I found there are many posts and modules help parse bearer token, but I didn't found any help create one.

How should I properly generate a bearer token in node.js server?

Comment: Disregard the downvoter. There was nothing wrong with this question, thanks for asking it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) token. To generate a token check out [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) module.

You can generate a token like this:

```
let token = jwt.sign({
  exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60),
  data: 'foobar'
}, 'secret');
```

There are plenty other examples in the docs.